# Azure AD: Exception acquiring token for some first time users

Tags: azure-active-directory, openid-connect, asp.net-core-1.0

I have an application using the converged application registration. As is normal with this types of applications, when a user goes to the site, they are redirected to Azure AD (AAD) to log in. If they have not consented to the permissions yet, they are then presented with a screen to consent to permissions (which include Graph API delegated permissions).

Once they accept and are redirected back to the site, the application immediately redeems the token to make calls to the Graph API. For a small number of users, an exception is thrown when the application attempts to redeem the token. It is a `Microsoft.Identity.Client.MsalUiRequiredException` exception. Based on what I've read, it sounds like AAD doesn't believe the user has consented yet, but they had to in order to get this far. The site always requests the same permissions (they are not dynamically set). If the user waits a few minutes and tries again, everything works fine.

Here's the error message I've left out sensitive info:

> Unhandled remote failure.AADSTS65001: The user or administrator has
>   not consented to use the application with ID '{guid}' named '{app
>   name}'. Send an interactive authorization request for this user and
>   resource.

I feel like this may be a race condition where the user consents, but before the consent has replicated across the regions, the request to redeem the token is routed to a region that is not yet aware of the consent, so it throws the previously mentioned exception.

I've only ever seen this happen to users on their initial login when they consent to the permissions.

Has anyone else experienced this? Better yet, has any one else found a fix for this?

Comment: http://shouldiblamecaching.com/ Seriously though, have not seen this myself. It does sound like a caching problem in Graph API.

Comment: Is it a public client application (Desktop/Mobile app) ?

Comment: No, this is a web application. The URL is publicly accessible, but you cannot log in unless you have a valid user in my AAD instance.